# Correlate days & number of year on Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, days

I need to itinerate the days of the week on the following tuple and assign it to a day of the year (from 1 to 365). I have to do it without transforming the tuple in a list. Of course, my first attempt was to transform the tuple on a list, extend it and use zip() function. Any ideas of how to do it without transforming the tuple with loops?

Thanks a lot!

```
days = ("lunes","martes","miércoles","jueves","viernes","sábado","domingo")
list_days = list(days)
number = list(range(1,366))
list_compl = list_days*53
list_compl

for j,i in zip(list_compl,number):
    print(i,j)
```

Comment: What about dicts?

Answer (score 0):

To cycle over the list of days, you can use the `cycle` function from the `itertools` package.

```py
import itertools

days = ("lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo")
number = range(1, 366)

for j, i in zip(itertools.cycle(days), number):
    print(i, j)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler answer than the one from @thomas_bssnt could be to do this

```
days = ("lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo")

for i in range(1, 366):
    print(i, days[i%7-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! What does it mean i%7-1? It is the very first time I see it! Thanks again, :)

Comment: In python `%` is the modulo operator, it return the rest of the euclidian division between the two numbers. For example, `a%b` return the rest of the euclidian division of `a` by `b`. 
Here we are going to apply `i%7` this means that the output will be between `0` and `6` as the rest of the euclidian division by `7` can't be greater or equal to `7 `. We are adding the -1 because `1%7` is equal to `1` and we want to have 0.

Comment: Thanks!! Noted! You helped me a lot!